# jscrollpane horizontal mousewheel

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, mousewheel, horizontal-scrolling

I have been unsuccessful getting the mouse wheel to scroll a horizontal jscrollpane.  Does anyone have experience with this and can offer some pointers.

In the comments of the js file I see the following update just a couple of months ago
*// 2.0.0beta3 - (2010-08-27) Horizontal mousewheel, mwheelIntent, keyboard support, bug fixes*

I've looked on the github issues page and Kelvin's FAQ and known issues pages as well as the google group and nothing makes me think this shouldn't be possible.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are using a version of the mousewheel plugin which came out after 2010-08-27 - changes were made to the mousewheel plugin as well as to jScrollPane to make it work. On my demo pages I am using 3.0.4:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js

If that doesn't help then can you confirm whether horizontal scrolling works for you on my demo pages. It does in all browsers I have tried which have a mouse capable of horizontal wheel motions (or on a macbook trackpad).

Comment: I did pull down the latest mousewheel.  On your demo page, the horizontal scroll isn't working for me.  I've used ie,chrome, safari with the same results.  only vertical scrolling seems to work, nothing else.

Comment: also, I just realized that perhaps I a miss understanding how this should work.  In horizontal-only mode, i would expect the same wheel that moves the vertical scroll to move the horizontal scroll, is that correct?

Comment: confirmed that shift scroll actually works, so the horizontal scrolling just isn't what I expected but probably works exactly as implemented.

Comment: The idea is that horizontal scrolling responds to a mouse wheel which is able to scroll horizontally. My Microsoft wheel mouse does this when you push the wheel to the side. And the track pad on my macbook also does it.
Personally I think that the "vertical mouse wheel makes horizontal scrolling happen" (like in the Apple app store) is really unintuitive and bad from a usability perspective so I'm unlikely to implement it in jScrollPane.

Comment: sounds good, I can't really comment on the intuitive part since I've been using JScrollHorizontalPane (based on your old stuff) for so long it is second nature.  Thanks for the prompt feedback and great library.

Answer (score 11):

You could use something like this:

```
$('.scroller').each(function(){
    var scrollPane = $(this).jScrollPane();
    var api = scrollPane.data('jsp'); 
    scrollPane.bind( 
        'mousewheel',
        function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) 
        { 
            api.scrollByX(delta*-50);
            return false;
        } 
    ); 
});
```

Change -50 to another value to change the speed and direction of the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a mousewheel detection plugin by Brandon Aaron:
http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos

It works well in FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome, IE8+.

Comment: i have this plugin referenced and if I understand correctly, Kelvin is actually doing the binding within his code.  So unless I am missing something I should only have to reference it and everything is taken care of?

Answer (score 0):

i have used the below link 1.5 yeears back and it worked for sure , please let me know if you have any doubts.

```
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html
```

Comment: see this link it has horizontal http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrow_positions.html

Answer (score -1):

This works on my site perfectly.

Try.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('div.scroll-pane')
        .bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
           var scrollPane = $(this).jScrollPane();
           var api = scrollPane.data('jsp'); 
           scrollPane.bind( 'mousewheel',function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) 
        { 
            api.scrollByX(delta*-50);
            return false;
        } 
         ); 
        });
});
```

Comment: You're binding the mousewheel event twice - so with each mousewheel event you're binding another event to scrollPane element. With that code I had experienced the behaviour of accelerating speed of scroll.